# How can i use "strcspn" or "any other Approach to change key of Array" to get an appropriate result?

Tags: php, logic

I have this array

```
$array = array('keyPad'=>'pencil', 
               'timeDuration'=>'exam', 
               'check_year'=>2004, 
               'currentTime'=>'12:06:25')
```

and I want to convert it to this array

```
array('Key Pad'=>'pencil', 
      'Time Duration'=>'exam',  
      'Check Year'=>2004 ,
      'Current Time'=>'12:06:25')
```

I had tried this code

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
    if(strpos($key,"_")){
        $namesArray = explode("_",$key);
        $name = ucwords(implode(" ",$namesArray));
        //echo $name;die;   
    }elseif(strcspn($key, 'ABCDEFGHJIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')){
        //how
    }
}
```

Comment: in their **strcspn** if check "check_year" it gives total no of counting of string..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it with the following approach:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if(strpos($key,"_")){
        $array[str_replace('_', ' ', $key)] = $array[$key];
        unset($array[$key]);
    } else if(preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $key) && (!ctype_upper($key[0]) || preg_match_all('/[A-Z]/', $key, $matches) > 1)){
        $array[preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/s','$1 $2', $key)] = $array[$key];
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

I loop over the array using `foreach` just as you do.

Then I check for underscores (as you do) and replace them using str_replace to set the key to the result of the replace. After this I remove the old key.

If there are no underscores, I check for uppercase characters in the key - but not if only the first letter is uppercase.

Then I do the same as obove (replace the CamelCase by space and unset the old key.

Tests:

```
Key               Result
-------------------------------
keyPad            key Pad
Keypad            Keypad
key_pad_test      key pad test
timeDuationTest   time Duration Test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the very beginning of foreach loop and remove the strcspn part:

```
$key = preg_replace('/([A-Z])/', '_\\1', $key)
```